# ASP.NET identity auth session and cookie works only locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity and it works perfectly locally with regular login and external login. For some reason when I publish my project and run it on remote server I have about 1 minuet of my authorization session. After 1 minute I'm redirected to my login page. (No error message)

My startup auth config:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, VisU>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
                   {
                       ClientId = "***",
                       ClientSecret = "***",
                       SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                       Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                       {
                           OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                       {
                           context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:name", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));
                           context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:email", context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)));
                           context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Google"));
                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                   }
               };
               app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
}
```

My Account controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<string> Login()
{
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Request.Form["emailLogin"], Request.Form["passwordLogin"], true, shouldLockout: true);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return ViewBag.ReturnUrl ?? "https://localhost:44300/Account";
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return Resources.Multilang.ERRORLockedOut;
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    //Mail or password are incorrect
                    return Resources.Multilang.ERRORInvalidLogin;
                default:
                    return Resources.Multilang.ERRORInvalidLogin;
            }
  }
```

What could be a reason for this behavior?

("https://localhost:44300/" is changed to my domain name when published.)

Comment: _Guessing_: Any `roles` to a resource that would restrict access (and redirect)?

Comment: Yes. I'm login with user in role admin and working on page restricted to admin roles. Locally works good, but on server I'm redirected to login page after 1 minute.

Comment: How many servers are there? If >1 and behind a load balancer you may get session issues.

Comment: Did you set a machine key in your web.config?  This is what .NET uses to encrypt/decrypt the auth cookie among other things.  If not set and you are on some type of shared hosting (such as Azure), the different web servers will not be able to read the cookie.  By setting a machine key, you ensure that any instance of your application will be able to read the relevant cookies needed to perform authorization.

Comment: Tommy, thank you so much! don't know how I missed it! Please post your comment as an answer to my question so I could mark it as an answer!

Comment: @levkaster - just saw your comment, added an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common causes of this issue is not setting the `MachineKey` element in your web.config.  The `MachineKey` is what is used to encrypt and decrypt things such as your authorization cookie.  When the `MachineKey` element is not set, IIS will make up a `MachineKey` for you.

Where this becomes an issues isif you are publishing your application to 3rd party web hosting such as Azure or GoDaddy. These providers typically have the web applications on more than one web server.  Since the web server will makeup its own `MachineKey` if one is not set, each web server hosting your application will have its own `MachineKey`.  The end result is that web server A issues and encrypts the authorization cookie.  If the next request goes to web server B, it will not be able to decrypt and read the cookie, so it assumes you are not logged in.

Setting a `MachineKey` in your web.config ensures that each web server hosting your application can encrypt and decrypt the authorization cookie without issue.